# Opposite of a Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

The rules of the regex are simple:

- Split by NOT: a whitespace `" "` followed by  'OR' or '|' :

Example:

```
"thing to say" france (true)

"thing to say" OR thing (false)

"thing to say" | thing (false)
```

I'm trying to find a regex to help me do that (with a pregs_split)

I only could do something like `/\||OR| \|| OR| \| | OR |\| | OR/` really basic but I need a regex for the opposite case.

Comment: Do you mean a whitespace? and not `_`

Comment: yes @DarylGill a whitespace

Comment: Why not just remove "OR" and "|" from the input?

Comment: I don't control the input, and I need to perform an action onl when the input doesn't have "OR" or "|"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative lookahead

```
"thing to say" ?(?!\||OR)
```

EDIT: your comment `split by a space followed by "OR" or "|"` is different than what I understood your question to be.  In that case it would actually make sense to use a *positive* lookahead:

```
/ (?=\||OR)/
```

Comment: you mean something like 
`$matches = preg_split('?(?!\||OR)', $stringToSplit);`

Comment: Well your question was a bit unclear .. I thought you were just trying to match *not* that regex.  You can't split by the lookahead because it does not consume anything.  You need a more specific regex.  If you just split by a space it splits every word

Comment: yeah exaclty, I need to split by a space followed by "OR" or "|" that's why im a little bit confused

Comment: Your edit works as a charm, but what if I wanted to find the opposit of that ? I mean find the case when there is a space but not followed by 'OR' or '|'

Comment: @vladimire In that case use what you had `/ (?!\||OR)/`, but that is a *lot* of spaces, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it means my rules are no right for this kind of problem. Hum, let me explain it one more time, you may be able to help me:
- `"thing to say" word (true)`
- `"thing to say" OR word (false)`
- `"thing to say" | word (false)`
How would a regex look like if I want it to return true in the first case ? I think we should add an other whitespace to the rule ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29124/discussion-between-explosion-pills-and-vladimire)